# Hide a field based on checkbox

Tags: commerce

I want to hide the price for specific products in a product display. I have added a checkbox to the product display type and when it is checked I want to hide the price.

I have figured out that I can hide the field with hide($build['product:commerce_price']) in hook_node_view_alter but the problem is I don't know how to get the value of the checkbox. var_dump($build["field_hide_price"]) outputs null;

Answer (score 1):

The [conditional field](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module will do this for you. In this module when certain fields are selected, get value, ... other operations (hiding,removing,make it required,...) may happen

Comment: I have figured out the price is a line item type and not a field so I cant hide it with conditional field?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to use the [form API states](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example%21form_example_states.inc/function/form_example_states_form/7), this will allow you to use Drupal's built in jQuery to hide and show the price based on the state of the checkbox.

Example syntax:

```
'#states' => array(
  'action_to_take_on_this_form_element' => array(
    'jquery_selector_for_another_element' => array(
      'condition_type' => value,
    ),
  ),
)
```